# Unable to run test for r2dbc with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2, r2dbc

I am following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-r2dbc) link to implement R2DBC with spring data. [That project](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5-data-reactive) has huge POM as it demos other features too. So I try to have only dependencies I need for spring boot and R2DBC with H2.

My pom is as:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--For testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--For reactive-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!---->
<dependencies>
```

I have then defined repository as:

```
public interface ReactiveFeatureRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Feature, UUID> {
}
```

Feature is the entity class.

I have configured h2 in application.properties in src/test/resources:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

In test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ReactiveFeatureRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    ReactiveFeatureRepository rfr;

    @Autowired
    DatabaseClient client;

    @Autowired
    H2ConnectionFactory factory;
...
...
}
```

But when I try to run test, I get huge logs which list 'Poitive matches' and  'Negative matches', and finally:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
'x.y.z.ReactiveFeatureRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'rfr'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'x.y.z.ReactiveFeatureRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at
```

As compared to sample project, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

For Spring Data R2dbc, the db connection config prefix is *spring.r2dbc*.

Check [my example here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/legacy/boot-data-r2dbc)

> You can ignore the H2/R2dbc config if there is H2 R2dbc driver in the classpath.

There is [a example for testing Repository](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/legacy/boot-data-r2dbc/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java) for H2.

For other database supports and writing testing codes with TestContainers, check other r2dbc examples in [this repository](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample).

**Update**: There is a new [R2dbc Examples Project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample), which demos R2dbc feature in Spring Boot 2.4+/Spring Data R2dbc/Spring 5.3 R2dbc module.

Comment: Half of your links are now dead.

Comment: @desertnaut R2dbc itself is updated frequently, the old examples were moved to `legacy` folder(all links are updated now). To use the latest R2dbc, check the [R2dbc Examples](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample).